# Why platform device need to be registered as another device?

Tags: linux, driver, linux-device-driver

I'm a beginner in Linux driver development. I've been searched many references but i still didn't get this. That's why i ask here, sorry for that.

I found the codes in my project that the device is registered as a misc device via `misc_register` in platform driver's probe function. What make me confused is that, in my view, the physical device represented by `platform_device` has been matched with the `platform_driver` already, that means the device has been "driven" successfully. Then why we need another misc device? If these misc device and platform device is representing the same physical device, how they bind with each others?

Answer (score 0):

`misc_register()` is mostly just a way of registering an individual character device (character special file) without using up a whole new major device number for a character device driver. It is accessible from user space using the file operation handlers specified by the `struct file_operations` referred to by the `fops` member of the `struct miscdevice` being registered by `misc_register()`.

Comment: so why is not the platform device providing the file operations but the misc device provide that? why platform device can't has any file operations member?

Comment: @Xingx1 The driver code that is calling `misc_register()` is responsible for providing the file operation handlers. The driver for the platform device *could* provide its own code for registering a complete character device driver with its own major device number, but that is often overkill. Also, it is not uncommon for platform device drivers (and other bus client drivers such as PCI device drivers) to register devices with other subsystems. That is more the norm than the exception.